# HTML report for django tests

Tags: django, testing

I have a Django project containing an API (created with rest framework if that counts anywhere). I have added some tests for the API but in order to have an overall view of the tests, either passing, either failing or missing, I need to create an HTML report. 
When the tests are finished a HTML table report should be generated which shows the endpoints and HTTP responses covered during tests, the results of the tests plus the combinations which are missing the tests.

Unfortunately I cannot understand how should I do that. I know that coverage can give me a detailed html report, but that's not what I need, I need something like this:

| Endpoint description      |  200  |  400  |  403  |  404  | 
| GET /endpoint1       | PASS  | PASS  |PASS   |  N/A  | 
| POST /endpoint1      | PASS  | FAIL  |MISSING|  N/A  |

Does anybody has any idea about that? Maybe some libs that could help out with that or what strategy should I use for that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your tests are the bunch of `TestCase` sublcasses and you run them by executing `./manage.py test`, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but this is my solution to outputting a HTML test report for Django tests. (based on [HtmlTestRunner cannot be directly used with Django DiscoverRunner](https://github.com/oldani/HtmlTestRunner/issues/12))

The following classes if placed in tests/html_test_reporter.py can be used as a DiscoverRunner which is patched to use HTMLTestRunner.

```
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
from HtmlTestRunner import HTMLTestRunner

class MyHTMLTestRunner(HTMLTestRunner):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Pass any required options to HTMLTestRunner 
        super().__init__(combine_reports=True, report_name='all_tests', add_timestamp=False, **kwargs)

class HtmlTestReporter(DiscoverRunner):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        # Patch over the test_runner in the super class.
        html_test_runner = MyHTMLTestRunner
        self.test_runner=html_test_runner
```

Then this is run with:

```
python manage.py test -v 2 --testrunner tests.html_test_reporter.HtmlTestReporter
```

By default Django projects use django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner to search for tests and  then use PyTest to run them.  HTMLTestRunner can be used with PyTest to output a HTML test report, but it does seem possible to configure PyTest to use HTMLRunner through DiscoverRunner.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Django uses the python's standard `unittest` library, you'll have to tweak some of its parts.

**First**, you'll need some way to specify which tests actually test which endpoint. A custom decorator is handy for that:

```
from functools import wraps

def endpoint(path, code):
    """
    Mark some test as one which tests specific endpoint.
    """
    def inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    inner._endpoint_path = path
    inner._endpoint_code = code
    return inner


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @endpoint(path='/path/one', code=200)
    def test_my_path_is_ok(self):
        response = self.client.get('/path/one?foo=bar')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    @endpoint(path='/path/one', code=404)
    def test_my_path_expected_errors(self):
        response = self.client.get('/path/one?foo=qux')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)

    def test_some_other_stuff(self):
        # this one will not be included in our results grid.
        pass
```

You could use a "magical" approach (e.g. special methods' names to guess the endpoint they are testing) instead, but [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), right?

**Then**, you need a way to collect the results of your tests - specifically, of that which test the endpoints. Here we make a (very draft) subclass of `unittest.TestResult` to handle it:

```
class EndpointsTestResult(TestResult):
    def __init__(self):
         super(EndpointsTestResult, self).__init__()
         self.endpoint_results = {}

    def addError(self, test, err):
        super(EndpointsTestResult, self).addError(test, err)
        if hasattr(test, '_endpoint_path'):
            branch = self.endpoint_results.setdefault(getattr(test, '_endpoint_path'), {})
            branch[getattr(test, '_endpoint_code')] = 'MISSING'

    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        # similar as addError()

    def addSuccess(self, test):
        # similar as addError()
```

**Finally** it's time to actually output our results. Let's make a sublass of the `unittest.TextTestRunner` and specify it in our custom runner:

```
class EndpointsTestRunner(TextTestRunner):
    def _makeResult(self):
         self._result = EndpointsTestResult()
         return self._result

    def run(self, test):        
        super(EndpointsTestRunner).run(test)
        # After running a test, print out the table
        generate_a_nifty_table(self._result.endpoint_results)


class EndpointsDjangoRunner(django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner):
    test_runner = EndpointsTestRunner
```

Now we have our custom `EndpointsDjangoRunner`, and we should specify it in the `settings.py`:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'path.to.the.EndpointsDjangoRunner'
```

That's it. Please let me know if you spot any awkward errors in the code.

Comment: Starting implementation in a while according to your answer! I'll let you know for sure how it went! Many thanks!

Comment: When using the decorator and trying to test the implementation, I face a `TypeError: endpoint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)` error. The first argument, the func one, shouldn't be the function that it decorates?

Comment: Maybe the `func` arg should be inner's method arg and not the decorator's

Comment: @koslib, try the (slightly) updated version. Does it help? Unfortunately, right now I can't check and test my code, will try to do it a bit later.

Comment: Alex, it seems to work. Now I'm making progress in integrating it with the existing django-nose testing suite that our project needs.

Comment: @koslib, I'm really happy the answer helped you. Please consider marking it as accepted, so that the others can rely on it.